# Android TextView Marquee not working(No XML)

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I have tried all the solutions here but the marquee is not working in my textview

Below is my textview which I am creating programmatically without using any XML layout file.

```
    marqueeMsgTileTextView = new TextView(this);
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setTextSize(20);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams marqueeMsgTileTextViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    marqueeMsgTileTextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    marqueeMsgTileTextViewParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setText("Some Text");
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0DFF0000"));
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setSingleLine();
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    marqueeMsgTileTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


    //Adding View to layout
    rLayout.addView(marqueeMsgTileTextView, marqueeMsgTileTextViewParams);
```

I can see the text in the text view but does not have the marquee effect. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926557/textview-marquee-programmatically

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have tried that. Doesnt work when i tried.

Answer (score 0):

add below property to make it working.

```
marqueeMsgTileTextView.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response. I tried adding it. It still doesn't move.

Comment: @D'yerMak'er have to `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project.